# Make sortable div resizeable with jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-resizable

I am using jQuery UI Sortable 'portlets'.

I want to add Resize function to it as in [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/)

I have tried my Sortable in [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7DM3Q/)

My Code:

```
$(function() {
    $(".column").sortable({
    connectWith: ".column"
    });
    $(".portlet").addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all")
    .find(".portlet-header")
    .addClass("ui-widget-header ui-corner-all")
    .prepend("<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick'></span>")
    .end()
    .find(".portlet-content");

    $(".portlet-header .ui-icon").click(function() {
       $(this).toggleClass("ui-icon-minusthick").toggleClass("ui-icon-plusthick");
       $(this).parents(".portlet:first").find(".portlet-content").toggle();
    });
    $(".column").disableSelection();
});
```

Comment: I have added the resizable to it. Is this what you wanted? http://jsfiddle.net/csicky/7DM3Q/8/

Comment: Yes..But while re-sizing the 2 divs gets override..Can you avoid override.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have a *fixed width* `.column` and then have the ability to resize an element to be wider than the column width. Let the `.column` width be `auto` and move the width to the `.portlet` - [**see demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/WFPaj/) or below for the change.

```
.column {
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}
.portlet {
    width: 170px;
    margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
}
```

Also, as @SanketS already answered and @Rudy commented, you need to add `$('.portlet').resizable()` to make the elements resizable.

Answer (score 3):

Add `$( ".portlet" ).resizable();` in your jquery code.
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7DM3Q/12/)

Comment: @Pravin Kumar please see DEMO in my answer which i have modified. I have changed .column and .portlet css class.